# End a text box of it's parent layout

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a relative layout inside that I have one textview and another button

[image]

**button is aligned perfectly but I want the textview end should be it's parent center.**
[image]

my XML lookes like

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Tour_Expense_List_Detail_Tbl">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/color_button"
                    android:onClick="SaveData"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTotalAmtVal"
                    style="@style/ButtonText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Total Amount: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#2E2E2E"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for your problem. You can use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true".
```

But it will make your "Total Amount" TextView in center. But you want You last character touch the center point. So you can make another "Blank TextView" and place it on center using centerInparent and then put your "TotalAmount" textview to its left.

```
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/blank_centered_text"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTotalAmtVal"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                **android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/blank_centered_text"**
                android:text="Total Amount: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#2E2E2E"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it use `LinearLayout` in `RelativeLayout` and then each of your Element (ie. `Button`& `TextView`) can use `layout_weight` property.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Tour_Expense_List_Detail_Tbl">
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Row1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"                     
                android:background="@drawable/color_button"
                android:onClick="SaveData"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTotalAmtVal"
                style="@style/ButtonText"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"                     
                android:text="Total Amount: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#2E2E2E"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in that case my application not gonna be device independent if I use layout_weight

Comment: @bumba it will be restricted depending on your parent ie the `relative layout`

Comment: then tell me what should I put layout_weight in that TextView

Comment: if you want both to be equal its `1`

Comment: you could also use % instead e.g. layout_weight = "50%"